# Has a uniform estimate in k of the inf-sup constant for hp-DG methods for the Stokes problem been established?

Tags: navier-stokes, discontinuous-galerkin, incompressible

In Theorem 6.2 of their 2003 paper on ["Mixed hp-DGFEM for incompressible flows. SIAM J. Numer. Anal., 40(6), 2171–2194"](http://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/S0036142901399124?journalCode=sjnaam), D. Schötzau, Ch. Schwab, and A. Toselli prove a bound of the $\inf$-$\sup$ constant of the Stokes problem which decreases by $1/k$ if $k$ is the polynomial degree of an hp-discontinuous Galerkin method.

Numerical examples suggest that this estimate may not be sharp.

Is anybody aware of an improved estimate, possibly independent of $k$?

Comment: Is [this](http://www.worldscientific.com/doi/abs/10.1142/S0218202503002970?journalCode=m3as) the paper you are referring to in your question?

Comment: Paul, if I remember correctly it is: http://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/S0036142901399124?journalCode=sjnaam

Schötzau, D., Schwab, C. & Toselli, A. (2003) Mixed hp-DGFEM for incompressible flows. SIAM J. Numer.
Anal., 40(6), 2171–2194.

Answer (score 5):

For interior penalty type HDG methods we have recently shown that $1/\sqrt{k}$ is possible (Proposition 6.10) and this bound is valid for several element types. In Remark 6.11 there is also a discussion about known results from the literature for other methods.

To my knowledge there exist no uniform results for hp-DG methods yet. I would however also be interested in new ideas and recent developments.

**References**

Egger, Waluga. hp-Analysis of a Hybrid DG Method for Stokes Flow, 2013 ([link](http://imajna.oxfordjournals.org/cgi/content/abstract/drs018?ijkey=kwbzr8Sj7m8wI0p&keytype=ref)).

Answer (score 5):

The problem was solved recently: [Lederer/Schöberl: Polynomial robust stability analysis for H(div)-conforming finite elements for the Stokes equations](https://arxiv.org/abs/1612.01482)

Answer (score 1):

The inf-sup constant for a continuous-velocity space is a lower bound for the corresponding DG space, therefore one can take the discontinuous analogue of any uniformly stable continuous space.  Two natural choices are $Q_k - Q_{\min(k-2, \lambda k)}$ where $0 < \lambda < 1$ and $Q_k - P_{k-1}$.  This was pointed out in Section 9 of [Toselli, *$hp$ Discontinuous Galerkin Approximations
for the Stokes Problem*, 2002](ftp://magellan-03.math.ethz.ch/hg/pub/sam-reports/reports/reports2002/2002-02.pdf).  Note that the latter space is not uniformly stable with respect to aspect ratio.  Recall also the anisotropically-enriched spaces of [Ainsworth and Coggins (2000)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1137/S0036142999365400) that provide a logarithmic stability bound, though I think these are of limited practical utility.

The spaces above are not very satisfying because normally one would hope to raise the pressure approximation order when going to a discontinuous velocity.  One practical reason for this is to simultaneously obtain optimal approximation order and uniform inf-sup stability with respect to aspect ratio. For example, DG using $Q_k - Q_{k-1}$ is uniformly stable with respect to aspect ratio (see the sequel,
[Schötzau, Schwab, Toselli, *Mixed $hp$-DGFEM for incompressible flows II:
Geometric edge meshes*, 2004](http://dx.doi.org/10.1093/imanum/24.2.273)), for which there is no known analogue in the continuous Galerkin world, causing one to use the suboptimal space $Q_k - Q_{k-2}$ to obtain uniform stability with respect to aspect ratio.